# Application closes while sending position phonegap android

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I have spent last 3 days until I got gps working on android using phonegap to develope application.

I am using example to understand how it works but I have some problem when I try to send position to a data base.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Properties Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {
        enableHighAccuracy : true,
        maximumAge : Infinity,
        timeout : 15000
    });
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');



    var id = 1;
    pagina = window.open( "http://mywebpage:80/open/posicionCamion.php?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lon=" + position.coords.longitude + "&id=" + id);
    pagina.close();                  

    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          +                                   position.timestamp          + '<br />';

}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If I delete pagina.window and pagina.close lines, it works fine. But I want to send position to a php file each 15 seconds and this php file will update the DB each time.

With these lines, application closes but nothing is sended. There is a way to do what I want?

I tested php file using a webbrowser and it works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.open()` opens a browser window, which will not work as expected in devices. Try replacing the `window.open()` call with an ajax request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callAjax(url){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url, false); 
    req.send();
    if(req.status == 200 || req.status == 0) {
        alert(req.responseText);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way using ajax to do that with a line or two? All examples I find, have to create XMLHttpRequest object and it is not so simple as what I am using.

Comment: i generally use jquery as it is really easy, i have put the function in answer which should work.

Comment: It works!! Thank you!! Now it doesn't close and I can keep using my app.